# Applet repaint frequency

Tags: java, applet

I want to create a Rubber-banding line using applet. Here is my code:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Vector;

public class RubberLines extends Applet implements MouseMotionListener {
    public void init() {
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }    
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        draw=true;
        X.add(e.getX());
        Y.add(e.getY());
        System.out.println(X.get(0));
        System.out.println("mouse is being dragged at location (" + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY() + ")");
    }    
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("mouse is being moved at location (" + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY() + ")");
    }     
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
                initX=X.get(0);
                initY=Y.get(0);
                finalX=X.get(X.size()-1);
                finalY=Y.get(Y.size()-1);
                //g.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100);
                if(draw)
        g.drawLine(initX, initY, finalX, finalY);
        g.setColor(Color.green);
           System.out.println(initX);
           System.out.println(finalY); 

           //repaint();    
    }   
    int initX,initY;
    int finalX,finalY;
    Vector<Integer> X=new Vector<Integer>();
    Vector<Integer> Y=new Vector<Integer>();
    boolean draw=false;    
}
```

However, the line didn't show up when I dragged the mouse until I change the size of applet(which means repaint). But when I added `repaint()`, the applet just repaints itself non-stop.

How to understand this `repaint()` and how to fix the problem please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But when I added repaint(), the applet just repaint itself non-stop.

Don't invoke repaint() in a painting method.

Instead add the repaint() to the mouseDragged() method because this is where the event is generated.

Also, don't forget to invoke `super.paint()` in your painting method.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It is working. But I think I still have one bug. That is, when finishing the drawing of first line, I drag the mouse again and try to draw the 2nd line. However, because I use vector.get(0) as the starting point, that is not correct. How to fix it please?